# Blender animation not rendering after changing the length from 250 to 500

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

My animation in blender refuses to render. It will either be stuck on 0% for a while or close down the software.

I'm using cycles, my animation worked before i changed the placement of the camera. But since changing the camera and lengthening the frames from 250 to 500. It just doesn't seem to want to cooperate. I'm rendering a fluid scene and baking the fluid  works just fine.

I can post the blender file if that would help.

Comment: There is not enough information to know what's happening. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of  your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add elaborate on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

 Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: Set the output to Overwrite. I saw something similar when the animation frames were being skipped for already existing. If you are not already set the output file type to PNG. If Blender crashes(closes unexpectedly) run Blender from the command line and add the error message to your Question.